# Android,Using ConvertView in Heterogeneous List Adapters?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, convertview

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) say:

> ... Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of view types, so
>   that this View is ***always of the right type*** (see getViewTypeCount() and
>   getItemViewType(int)).

I tried [this way](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) to create `Heterogeneous List Adapters` and I had no problem.But I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018997/why-does-getview-return-wrong-convertview-objects-on-separatedlistadapter) and [this web page](http://sparetimedev.blogspot.com/2012/10/recycling-of-views-with-heterogeneous.html).They say it may be occurs problems:The wrong type of `ConvertView`.They propose to check if type of convertview is true or not? And this is inconsistent with Docs.

My questions:

When we ovrride `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int)` is it possible that convertview be from incorrect type?